# ValueError:"No such layer" error in tensorflow for inception v2 model

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement Ablation CAM using Inceptionv2 trained on on imagenet weights. For implementing I have to create a model inside the main model which take input as output of last convolutional layer and output as output of whole model. Whenever I run that code it is showing no such layer.

Here is my code

```
`%config Completer.use_jedi=False
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras.backend as K
import cv2
import matplotlib.cm as cm
%matplotlib inline`


model = tf.keras.models.load_model('D:\Project_data\exported_model')

img_path = 'fol_5.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(img_path)

img = cv2.resize(img, (450, 450), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

img = img[None, ...]

model.layers[2].summary()
```

Since the model is very big I am sharing first few layers and last few layers.

```
enterModel: "model"
```

| Layer (type) | Output Shape | Param # | Connected to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| input_1 (InputLayer) | [(None, 450, 450, 3)] | 0 | [] |
| conv2d (Conv2D) | (None, 224, 224, 32) | 864 | ['input_1[0][0]'] |
| batch_normalization (BatchNormalization) | (None, 224, 224, 32) | 96 | ['conv2d[0][0]'] |
| activation (Activation) | (None, 224, 224, 32) | 0 | ['batch_normalization[0][0]'] |
| conv2d_1 (Conv2D) | (None, 222, 222, 32) | 9216 | ['activation[0][0]'] |
| batch_normalization_1 (BatchNormalization) | (None, 222, 222, 32) | 96 | ['conv2d_1[0][0]'] |
| activation_1 (Activation) | (None, 222, 222, 32) | 0 | ['batch_normalization_1[0][0]'] |
| conv2d_2 (Conv2D) | (None, 222, 222, 64) | 18432 | ['activation_1[0][0]'] |
|  |  |  |  |
| block8_10 (Lambda) | (None, 12, 12, 2080) | 0 | ['block8_9_ac[0][0]', 'block8_10_conv[0][0]'] |
| conv_7b (Conv2D) | (None, 12, 12, 1536) | 3194880 | ['block8_10[0][0]'] |
| conv_7b_bn (BatchNormalization) | (None, 12, 12, 1536) | 4608 | ['conv_7b[0][0]'] |
| conv_7b_ac (Activation) | (None, 12, 12, 1536) | 0 | ['conv_7b_bn[0][0]'] |
| conv2d_203 (Conv2D) | (None, 12, 12, 2) | 3074 | ['conv_7b_ac[0][0]'] |
| global_average_pooling2d (GlobalAveragePooling2D) | (None, 2) | 0 | ['conv2d_203[0][0]'] |
| softmax (Softmax) | (None, 2) | 0 | ['global_average_pooling2d[0][0]'] |

## Model architecture ended

```
last_conv_layer = model.layers[2].get_layer(name='conv_7b_ac')


last_conv_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(model.layers[2].inputs, last_conv_layer.output)


classifier_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=last_conv_layer.output.shape[1:])


print(classifier_input)
print(model.layers[2].output)
#classifier_model=tf.keras.Model(classifier_input,model.layers[2].output)

for layer_name in classifier_layer_names:

    x = model.layers[2].get_layer(layer_name)(x)

classifier_model = tf.keras.Model(classifier_input, x)
```

Whenever I am running the cell containing classifier_model. It is throwing the following error.

Output is

```
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 12, 12, 1536), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'")
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='softmax/Softmax:0', description="created by layer 'softmax'")



ValueError: No such layer: conv2d_203 . Existing layers are [<keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x0000014695093370>, 
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x00000146950938E0>, <keras.layers.normalization.batch_normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x00000146955933D0>, 
<keras.layers.core.activation.Activation object at 0x0000014695593850>, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x0000014695593D60>,
<keras.layers.normalization.batch_normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x000001469593C5B0>, <keras.layers.core.activation.Activation object at 0x000001469593CA30>, 
................................................................................................................................ 
<keras.layers.core.activation.Activation object at 0x00000146AA4CFC40>, <keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x00000146AA4D8280>, 
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x00000146AA4D8340>, <keras.layers.core.lambda_layer.Lambda object at 0x00000146AA4D8B80>, 
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x00000146AA4E10A0>, <keras.layers.normalization.batch_normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x00000146AA4E1220>,
<keras.layers.core.activation.Activation object at 0x00000146AA4E1CA0>, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x00000146AA4E8220>, 
<keras.layers.pooling.GlobalAveragePooling2D object at 0x00000146AA4E8850>, <keras.layers.advanced_activations.Softmax object at 0x00000146AA4E8AF0>].
```

.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have a very similar issue.

Comment: while specifying the layer name, I was giving a space before layer name  something like   " layer2" rather than "layer2"